# Untrusted Certificates Warning with Fiddler certificates?

Tags: fiddler, fiddlercore

Installed the new version on Fiddler (V4.6.1.4) on 10/30.  Now when trying to use it to view/debug traffic from IE and from C# I keep getting "Security Alert" pop ups about "identity of this site or the integrity of this connection cannot be verified".

Does anyone know how to turn this off?  I haven't been able to find a way.

Answer (score 0):

This suggests that Windows hasn’t been configured to trust Fiddler’s root certificate. Please see http://textslashplain.com/2015/10/30/reset-fiddlers-https-certificates/ for a step-by-step guide to resetting your certificates.

Comment: Eric - This seems to have resolved the issues.  Thanks for the assist.